# Navigation Menu not rendering in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a navigation menu for my website to be used when people access the site on their phone. For some reason, I can see this working only on the fiddle I made, but not when I test it in my browser.

I've tested it with Chrome, and the latest version of IE, but I don't see the responsive navigation menu I made when I shrink my browser's size.

This is exactly what my javascript file looks like:

```
$("#nav").addClass("js").before('<div id="menu">&#9776; MENU </div>');
$("#menu").click(function(){
    $("#nav").toggle();

});

$(window).resize(function(){
    if(window.innerWidth > 768){
        $("#nav").removeAttr("style");

    }
});
```

Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Nuxj6/

And my CSS file and HTML file have the same code as in the fiddle. The only thing that is different is that I have another CSS file for the rest of my site. This CSS file is only for the navigation menu. I tried importing the CSS file with the navigation menu into my main CSS file, but it didn't work either.

I would appreciate any advice on fixing this issue. As I said, it works in the fiddle, but not in my browser. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems likely that there is a CSS cascade/override issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run your code when DOM is ready or `#nav` is parsed by browser, or jQuery cannot find `#nav`. So you may have 2 alternative ways:

- Run your code when Dom is ready just like:

  ```
  $(function() {
      $("#nav").addClass("js").before('<div id="menu">&#9776; MENU </div>');
      $("#menu").click(function(){
          $("#nav").toggle();

      });

      $(window).resize(function(){
          if(window.innerWidth > 768){
              $("#nav").removeAttr("style");

          }
      });
  });
  ```
- Put your js code at the bottom of your HTML.

#### Why jsfiddle works?

That's because jsfiddle will wrap js code with `$(window).load` like below if you use jQuery:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#nav").addClass("js").before('<div id="menu">&#9776; MENU </div>');
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been trying to figure this out for days, but this works!